# Facebook Sharer issue (always shows (+) and (%) behind every word)

Tags: facebook, share

I would like to ask how I can fix my Facebook sharer issue.
Whenever I want to share my article via Facebook sharer, it pops up the facebook window, which is totaLly ok. But in the window it shows pluses (+) and (%) behind every single word. Can You guys help me with it?
You can take a look here at my website: http://www.asiancrib.com/post/test-2/
Try to share the article, you will see the issue.

Comment: A screen shot would be nice. You are asking me to click on some 'share' link on a website I don't know while my browser is logged into Facebook - I am not going to do that.

Comment: a screenshot is not neccessary, nothing will get shared, it just opens a popup with the sharer.php.

Comment: debugger says you got 2 times og:url, you should fix that first: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: Can You please tell me step by step how? I am kinda amateur at this.. Thank You very much for Your help! :)

Comment: I am looking forward to fix it with your help, it is very important for my job to share articles, but not like this.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ and type your URL . you will notice a couple of things:

1. Your content already has + % in the description.  `<meta property="og:description" content="Here%E2%80%99s+a+list+of+the+top+10+most+beautiful+Asian+actress.+%E2%80%8B1.+Aishwarya+Rai+Bachchan+Aishwarya+was+crowned+Miss+World+in+1994.+With+her+blue-green+..>`

You need to clean this up : `<meta property="og:description" content="Here is a list of ......>`

2. Why do you have certain tags multiple times? while it won't break anything, it is not good practice.
3. The debugger will show this message :

   `Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:http://www.asiancrib.com'.
   Extraneous Property Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'fb:930663840297658'.`

As it suggests, these do not exist. Kindly delete the first one. Change the second one to 
`<meta property="fb:app_id" content ="930663840297658">`